# Paging performance in table join vs exist

Tags: mysql, sql

For example I have A, B, C, D, E tables and want to do listing with pagination.

Solution 1:

```
SELECT * 
FROM A, B, C, D
WHERE 
    A.id = B.aId AND
    B.id = C.bId AND
    C.id = D.cId AND
    C.x = "test" AND
    D.y = "123"
LIMIT 20
OFFSET 0
```

Solution 2:

```
SELECT * 
FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.id = B.aId
WHERE EXISTS
    (
        SELECT '1' 
        FROM C, D
        WHERE
            B.id = C.bId AND
            C.id = D.cId AND
            C.x = "test" AND
            D.y = "123"
    )
LIMIT 20
OFFSET 0
```

And execute second query

```
SELECT * FROM C, D WHERE C.id = D.cId AND C.bId IN (<previous SQL result>)
```

And then join ABCD by myself

Is that solution 2 more faster than 1? since that solution 2 only get 20 records in second query. And the first query don't need to join 4 tables together.

Comment: joins are around for 30 years now, it is really time you learn how to use them

Comment: also all databses have an EXOLAIN ANALYSE to check different performances

Comment: LIMIT-ing without ORDER-ing makes little sense.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/fetch-next-page

Answer (score 0):

You are probably comparing apples to oranges.

Without an `ORDER BY`, the `LIMIT` can provide random rows.  For example, if you are paginating and say `OFFSET 20` the next time, you might get some of the same rows.

Adding a suitable `ORDER BY` *may* make the query run much slower.  Again, "apples vs oranges".

Since you are filtering on C and D, it is better to do the `JOIN`.  That way, the Optimizer can start with one of them, thereby not necessarily scanning all of A and B.

Getting IDs from one query, then feeding them into another is *usually* a slow technique.

Yes, do use `JOIN ... ON` to specify how the tables are related.  Leave `WHERE` for filtering.